# Deleting pointer to object causes Break

Tags: c++, pointers, sdk, assertion

I am using an 3rd party SDK to obtain recorder information (http://pdn.pelco.com/content/creating-pelco-system)

Here is a small example of creating a System object and using it to get camera information.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windowsx.h"
#include "objbase.h"

#include "PelcoSDK/PelcoSDK.h"
#include "PelcoSDK/SystemCollection.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PelcoSDK::Startup();

        PelcoSDK::System system("admin:admin@pelcosystem://192.168.10.123:60001?alias=MyPelco");

        PelcoSDK::DeviceCollection deviceCollection = pSystem.GetDeviceCollection();
        for (deviceCollection.Reset(); deviceCollection.MoveNext();)
        {
            PelcoSDK::Device device(deviceCollection.Current());
            printf("\tDevice Name: %s\n", device.GetModelName());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The above works fine BUT I now wish to create a wrapper class around this behaviour so I want a pointer to a PelcoSDK::System member variable like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windowsx.h"
#include "objbase.h"

#include "PelcoSDK/PelcoSDK.h"
#include "PelcoSDK/SystemCollection.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PelcoSDK::Startup();

        PelcoSDK::System* pSystem = new PelcoSDK::System("admin:admin@pelcosystem://192.168.10.123:60001?alias=MyPelco");

        PelcoSDK::DeviceCollection deviceCollection = pSystem->GetDeviceCollection();
        for (deviceCollection.Reset(); deviceCollection.MoveNext();)
        {
            PelcoSDK::Device device(deviceCollection.Current());
            printf("\tDevice Name: %s\n", device.GetModelName());
        }

        delete pSystem;  <-- Crashes here
        pSystem = nullptr;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This works fine but when I go to delete the pointer then it throws a debug asertion every time:
[image]

[image]

Am I not able to use a pointer to this object??

Comment: *Where* does the crash happen? Try running the program in the debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash, letting you examine the values of involved variables as well as examine (and walk up) the function call stack. Walk up the call stack until you are at your code. As for *why* it crashes, there can be many reasons, including (but not limited to) you modifying the pointer, you writing beyond the boundaries somewhere, and many many more. Also, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it crashes exactly at the deletion of the pointer like my post says.

Comment: In the above two examples, the top one works but the bottom one crashes when I delete the pointer.

Comment: Then you need to look for other sources of the crash. Is the pointer you try to delete the same that `new` gave you? You don't attempt to write beyond boundaries somewhere? It could even be a bug in the Pelco SDK. Without seeing some complete code it's impossible for us to say really. And no, I'm not asking you to put up your complete program here, but to attempt to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the above snippets of code ARE the complete programs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No it's not. Where's the `main` function? What header files do you include? What libraries do you link with? And if the four lines of code is your complete `main` function body, then you should probably report it to Pelco as it could be a bug on their end (but then include a *complete* program, not just a few loose lines).

Comment: OK please see my EDIT for complete program for the pointer version.

Comment: Your main does not follow the example shown [here](http://pdn.pelco.com/content/initializing-pelco-sdk-application). I am not saying it is the cause of the crash. But you might want to give it a go.

Comment: @simon I added in the SHutdown and ::CoUninitialise and the delete still causes the crash.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Pelco SDK programming guide, there is a `Remove()` method for removing a system object. A system object is listed in the cache as other device object. Once you created a system object and using it. There are other objects that has reference to the system object. You simply cannot just delete the system object. You have to call the `Remove()` method to remove a system object. Also `System.Remove()` does not remove the object immediately. It is removed only after all references to that System object have been released.
I would suggest to using reference rather than pointer for wrapping your system object, such that you don't need to worry about deleting it.

Here is an example of what I mean wrap it using reference:

```
class MyPelcoWrapper
{
public:
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    MyPelcoWrapper()
        : mySystem("admin:admin@pelcosystem://...")
    {
        ...
    }

    PelcoSDK::System& GetSystem()
    {
        return mySystem;
    }

private:
    PelcoSDK::System mySystem;
};

int _tmain(...)
{
    ...

    PelcoSDK::Startup();
    ...
    MyPelcoWrapper wrapper;
    ...
    PelcoSDK::System& sys = wrapper.GetSystem();
    sys.GetDeviceCollection();
    ...

}
```

Comment: re: Also System.Remove() does not remove the object immediately. - I tried .Remove() and it still crashed but now I understand as its not removed immediately. Thanks.  I'm unsure how I can use a reference to a System object though as a reference needs to be initialised (and cant be reassigned) and I want a class which has a member variable of PelcoSDK::System which I can initialise in the constructor.

Comment: @Harry Boy: see my edited answer of how to wrap the system object and use it by reference.

Comment: I like your solution! But I need to be able to pass in the login details at a later stage. How can I do this?